# c# winforms GetCurrentDirectory returns C:\WINDOWS\System32\ design error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, ms-access, windows-forms-designer

I'm making like a cashier app with a winforms project and i need to use an access database and i used `System.IO.GetCurrentDirectory()`. But it returns `C:\WINDOWS\System32` on design time so it keeps popping up message boxes when i'm using the designer.

It also returns the correct directory when i run it.

Here's an example of my connection string:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
string dataPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
conn.ConnectionString = @"
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=" + dataPath + "/Data/Databases/database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Edit:

What happens when i try to open the designer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQjHa.png

Comment: what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: it is returning C:\WINDOWS\System32 on design time so message boxes keep popping up

Comment: how can the error occur when u start the designer ??? why don't u just exclude the database from the project and just keep it in the app folder....tht should fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this is happening but u can try :

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory

//or

Application.StartupPath

//or

System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

//or

System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

//or

System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: which one is the best and more reliable?

Comment: all of them return the same result, see which one works

Comment: none of those above work :( it's now giving me visual studio's program file path

Comment: Run outside visual studio and let me know the results

Comment: it works if i run it but if i open the designer a bunch of message box pop up from my exception handling and it says the path to the database is wrong and the message box just keeps popping up so i can't do nothing

Comment: then why not as soon as u write some codes,press F6,this will just build the solution,then u can go to the bin folder and run ur application from there,it's faster thn running from vs :) ..... And please make sure to mark it as answer if it helped

Comment: i mean i can't open the designer it just throws a thousand exceptions like add a textbox or something

Comment: u can connect to me on skype @Aousaf Rashid or click [here](https://join.skype.com/OMtchSekVwYj)

Comment: but my code worked right ? i'll be glad if u mark it as answer

Comment: how? i'm new :(

Comment: how can the error occur when u start the designer ??? why don't u just exclude the database from the project and just keep it in the app folder....tht should fix it :)